# GrADS script sometimes throws error while opening grib ctl file

Tags: grads

Getting this error for GrADS (SUN Grid Engine) logic. However, the grib file and its associated ctl file exist and are valid. If I try to re-run the grads script job, it succeeds. I just don't understand why it sometimes fails.

```
opening ctl file
/data/myprogram/20211027/gribs/mygribname.grb.ctl
Open Error:  Can't open binary data file
  File name = /data/myprogram/20211027/gribs/mygribname.grb
```

The funny thing is... the code is trying to open the ctl file and not the gribfile. Not sure why it even tried to open the gribfile instead.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer to my question. I had to study a little bit of GrADS so I could interpret the logs better. The error above is thrown when the file does not exist. In my case, the file was there. However, it was getting generated after it was accessed by the GrADS code. And sometimes, the file was getting written as GrADS code was trying to access it. I added timestamps to the operations with full iso mode. The operations were happening within milliseconds of each other.